# Checkbox to automatically resize a retina display screenshot

Tags: feature-request, editing, images

For users with the new MacBook Pro with retina display, screenshots have their dimensions doubled. For example, if I take a screenshot of a window, this is what I get:

[image: retina screenshot, not resized]

As you can see, when the image is displayed normally, it's too big.

The correct way to display these is to use

```
<img src="[url]" width="[half of image width]">
```

Which produces this:

[image]

On a retina display, this is rendered at native resolution; on a non-retina display, it's appropriately downscaled so that it remains the correct size.

**Can we get a checkbox on the image upload dialog that does the hard work for us?** This would make answering questions a lot easier without having to manually check the image width, divide by 2, and type in the HTML.

Something like this:

[image]

Comment: Yes, yes, yes and yes - I would love this. Please consider asking this on the main meta http://meta.stackoverflow.com/ - your wording and explanation are excellent. I'll gladly ask it there (taking your work) if you would prefer not to ask there.

Comment: We can no longer migrate questions older than a few weeks to a new site. Someone has to copy the text and ask it there

Comment: @bmike Thought I had done this earlier but apparently not. Anyway, here we go! http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161111/checkbox-to-automatically-resize-a-retina-display-screenshot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since we can't migrate this question to the main meta - please visit the main site and vote / comment on this request since it's unlikely it will get implemented for us until it gets implemented site wide.

- [Automatically resize high-resolution screenshots](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161111/checkbox-to-automatically-resize-a-retina-display-screenshot)

Answer (score 1):

There are many articles discussing [image @2x css](http://www.bing.com/search?q=image+%402x+css) but one of the simplest I've seen is by [WeedyGarden.net](http://weedygarden.net/2010/10/retina-display-and-css-background-images/)

This can be done with HTML4 and CSS2 using a media query and changing the CSS to call the high resolution image.

Answer (score -5):

I'd just as soon leave the original image size as is. Let the end client determine what the image will be scaled to if at all.

Update: Currently the best that can be done is to have a client-side script check the available space in the content area and request an appropriately sized image.

In the future new properties in the [CSS3 image module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-images/#the-object-fit) could deal with the issue (look at `object-fit` for one).

Comment: This is the problem I want to avoid, so that the screenshots are not horribly large.

Comment: It would be nice if clients actually handled scaling - if anyone knows one that works well - please answer with some details...